# SharePoint 2016 - Column Settings missing from column header drop down

Tags: 2016, column

I'm using SP 2016 and am trying to access the column settings. I've read you click the dropdown next to the column heading and it should show up... however all I get are the filter options. Do I need to enable something on the site to get the "column setting" options? Or is this not an optiona any more for 2016? Sure would like to access the settings to format the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SharePoint 2016,The column settings option is not available in the dropdown next to column heading in list view.

This option is available in SharePoint online and Office 365 SharePoint.

However you can access the column settings by navigating to List --> List settings --> click on column name in columns section.

Comment: Thanks! Disappointing but at least I know it's not me.